# Permission denied on writing into the hard drive

Tags: virtual-machine, unix, azure

I am trying to download files into an Azure virtual machine. It seems that I have 400 GB hard drive but as a not experienced user, I have saved the files within the `/dev/root` filesystem, which is obviously much smaller (120 GB).

When I try moving the files to the `/mnt` folder within the `/dev/sdb1` filesystem, I get `Permission denied`. In fact, even creation of a simple test file/folder leads to the same result (`Permission denied`). What should I do to utilize the hard drive?

```
Filesystem                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                                             119G  113G  6.1G  95% /
devtmpfs                                               28G     0   28G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                  28G  8.0K   28G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                 5.5G  1.3M  5.5G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                  28G     0   28G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                                            128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop0                                             64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop2                                             64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop4                                             74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/817
/dev/loop10                                            92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop5                                            486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
/dev/loop9                                            1.5M  1.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/184
/dev/loop8                                             92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop7                                            1.5M  1.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/181
/dev/loop11                                            54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19122
/dev/loop12                                            54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/sda15                                            105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                                             393G   56G  318G  15% /mnt
//gkoganmlsstorage.file.core.windows.net/code-<    >  5.0T  7.9G  5.0T   1% /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/<>/code
/dev/loop13                                            74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/864
/dev/loop3                                            486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/126
```

Comment: What do `df -hT /mnt` and `ls -ld /mnt` report in your case?

Comment: `/mnt` is also not a good download folder. Why not use something like `/home/USERNAME/Downloads`?

Comment: @harrymc, I have tried your method and it puts the files in the same file system, while I intend to move them to the alternative file system - the one associated with the hard drive

Comment: You've not answered the comment above mine, which will add useful information.

Comment: @u1686_grawity filters out the 4th line before the end (from the list published in the original question).

ls -ld /mnt --->>>
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Sep 10 09:18 /mnt

Comment: I have tried 'sudo chmod u+w /mnt' and it kind of worked but I am not sure if I did not create any additional problems on the operation system level

Comment: Please add details (including the requested details) to your question ([edit] it), not in comments.